# Does PHPUnit have a Scriptable Web Browser and Web Tests

Tags: php, phpunit, simpletest

Does PHPUnit have a Scriptable Web Browser and Web Test capabilities, e.g. to fetch a page from a PHP script served on localhost, and then to click on elements, fill out & submit forms and assert the returned page content?

I am familiar with SimpleTest, and it has excellent classes and assertions for this. Also, the Zend framework seems to have a PHPUnit extension. However, I cannot find docs/examples of how to do web testing with PHPUnit (out-of-the-box) to cover functionality like sessions, form handling, clicking, navigation, ajax, etc..

I am looking for a way to have PHPUnit test my server side PHP code through HTML, thus testing my application from the vantage point of a user/visitor. I am not looking for a browser extension or any other kind of record & playback test framework like Selinium.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't anything in PHPUnit to do what you are after.

Comment: What you're describing are not unit tests, but rather acceptance tests. Read about those.

Comment: @El_Vanja I am interested in integration and systems testing, and whether PHPUnit has any such capabilities. I can't tell from their docs. You?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-selenium-with-phpunit/) and before you discard it based on the title, this isn't about Selenium's record & play tool, it's about Selenium WebDriver. My previous company used it with PHP to automate acceptance test. We haven't used it with PHPUnit, scripts were done in another way.

Comment: @El_Vanja That's a nice plugin. You get to write PHPUnit tests as web tests, and it interacts with the server through a browser of your choice, which means you also get to see the browser's renderings. This is a great alternative. For now, I am still looking for a browser-less php-based web tester using PHPUnit. Thanks for the tip. Failing other input, this may become the preferred answer.

Comment: You can use this package https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing or https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/dusk . It's for browser testing. What you are looking for is browser testing.

Comment: @mohammad.kaab, thank you. I had dismissed it because I though it was Laravel. I took a second look after you brought it up. I can't tell -at first glance- how tightly the assertions are coupled to Laravel itself. Do you know whether all assertions work on HTML/HTTP that is not generated by Laravel? In other words, are there certain (Laravel-typical) constraints placed on the HTML for the testing to work?

Comment: You don't need to install Laravel, to have dusk or browser-kit-testing, they are both standalone packages, you can freely use them. You can check it from composer.json file in the repository

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you are looking to write are acceptance tests. Codeception is a popular tool for this in PHP & is built on top of PHPUnit. It lets you write tests that can navigate your pages & look like:

```
class FirstCest
{
    public function frontpageWorks(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->click('View More');
        $I->see('Details');
    }
}
```

https://codeception.com/

Comment: This is indeed nice. I haven't tried it, but will add here (for others) that according to the docs "It's PHP script that can check HTML page contents, click links, fill forms, and submit POST and GET requests. For more complex tests that require a browser use Selenium with WebDriver module."